# Where in metadata of a video in html5 is the fps saved?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, frame-rate

In order to fully implement my custom html5 video player, I need the the exact frame rate of a video. However I have not been able to find it yet and am using a standard value of 25.
Typically videos have a frame rate value in meta-data so I accessed meta-data using something like this:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
console.log(e);
};
```

However I can't find frame rate here. Maybe I am not reading metadata at all.
I can use your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try https://mediainfo.js.org ([github](https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js))

It works on ui only, no backend needed

I just implemented it and it looks like it worked perfectly fine (at least in Chrome v 70.0.3538.77) for gettting wide media information

It looks like modern browsers beginning to work with some binary libraries

Comment: Just wasted an entire morning, the .js file is small but it fetches a 2.5MB .wasm file to do the work.  Ouch.

Comment: Can this library be used against a remote file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm 95% sure the standard html5 video api does not expose the fps information, from what I've read in the past months - other apis like **MPEG-DASH** and **jwplayer** do present more / different data.

Your best bet would be to snoop around [w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) and similar mdn pages.

You can calculate this in realtime yourself and it should work most of the time but I can imagine there's a case or two when it wouldn't. Look at `PresentedFrames` and then do something like:

```
fps = video.time / PresentedFrames
```

view more about PresentedFrames [here](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics#presentedFrames) (currently proposal) and similar attributes at the same [link](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics).

Comment: Thanks brod, I also think that it is unlikely that fps is given as a property by the html video element. I was just hoping that it would be otherwise. 
I like your given solution but how do I calculate PresentFrames? Because the way to measure frames is to use fps and current time.
Is there another way to find PresentFrames?

Comment: @HasanWajahat I've updated my answer with a source that documents many different attributes that could be useful in calculating the fps (specifically the PresentedFrames)

Comment: Thanks for the share,
Sadly chrome has not implemented presentedFrames yet. Mozilla has done so but I need it for chrome.

Comment: what about `playbackRate`

Comment: and here i am trying to advance the time index and render on a canvas and see at what point in time it changes, only it doesn't work because i'm running off file:// and it won't let me look at the pixels!

Comment: @MuhammadUmer `playbackRate` is a real number indicating whether the playback is faster (values bigger than `1.0`) or slower (values smaller than `1.0`) than what the stream frame rate suggests.

Answer (score 0):

`mediainfo.js` works pretty good - even if used locally in a browser using 'http(s)://'.

To use it locally, just **make sure** you also download the accompanying `mediainfo.wasm` and **put it into the same directory** as `mediainfo.min.js`.

Alternatively you can install media-info using `npm`.

The only caveat is, that it doesn't run from the 'file://' protocol.